# Different CSS results on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css

I have this page with books and animated authors names. Theres around 35 books on the page.

http://kutsalkitap.org/kaynaklar/

When you get your mouse on a book, name of the author fades in and goes down slowly. It look perfect on chrome but, on mozilla, names goes way more down than it should be. Passes through the other books section.

I tried a few things but couldn't managed to fix it. Can someone help me?

Here is my css:

```
<style>
#nav li.parent {
    margin-left: 1px;

    width: 740px;
    height: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}
/* Effect 9: second text and borders */
 #nav li.parent a {
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 18px 20px;
}
#nav li.parent a::before, #nav li.parent a::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    content:'';
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, height 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, height 0.3s;
}
#nav li.parent a::after {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
#nav li.parent a span:first-child {
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#nav li.parent a span:last-child {
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0 0 0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-family: Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", "Book Antiqua", Georgia, serif;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);

}
#nav li.parent a:hover::before, #nav li.parent a:focus::before {
    height: 6px;
}
#nav li.parent a:hover::before, #nav li.parent a:hover::after, #nav li.parent a:focus::before, #nav li.parent a:focus::after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);

}
#nav li.parent a:hover span:last-child, #nav li.parent a:focus span:last-child {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inline elements are not cross-browser. in your case consider `<span>` and `<a>`. use `display: block` for those elements or if you don't need those to be block, simply use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` 
that should work for you.

Comment: also don't use top and bottom margin in the same element. some browsers collapse margin and some won't so it won't be cross-browser. in your case for `#nav li.parent` this selector instead of `margin: 10px` , use `margin: 0 10px 10px;`

Comment: sure i will help you @Burcak can you make fiddle?

Comment: or give me few mins, i will make a fiddle for you

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/mf0spgxk/4/ ] here is the fiddle. take a look. i have made only for 1st and second box. you should also remove `<br>` tags as @rJ7 said in his answer

Answer (score 1):

You just remove the `<br>` tag in between the class "text1" and "text2" in every `<a>` tag.

HTML:

```
<span class="text1" style="color:#000;font-size:24px;">Bir Satanistin Anıları</span>
        <span class="text2" style="color:#000;font-size:18px;">Hershel Smith</span>
```